# Blazor component is rendered but no lifecycle methods are called, no other methods can be invoked

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a pretty standard Razor pages project, and I've recently introduced Blazor components into the project.  I've added the _Host.cshtml, App.razor, and the other requirements to get Blazor working.  The Blazor components work fine when I'm at an endpoint that is exclusively Blazor components.  However, I want to embed Blazor components within my current .cshtml pages using something like

```
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<EditorComponent>(RenderMode.Server, new { Id = Model.Id}))
```

withing my cshtml page.  This syntax renders the component fine, but it doesn't run any of the Blazor lifecycle methods(OnAfterRenderAsync) or even something like a button calling back to a Task, in my EditorComponent component.

I've included the

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

at the end of  element on my layout page.  Am I missing something to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use the `component` tag helper instead.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/component-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

`<component type="typeof(EditorComponent)" render-mode="Server" param-Id=@Model.Id/>`

Comment: I've tried this and get the same outcome.  The component will render but still nothing 'works', no lifestyle methods run, I can't click buttons, etc.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Has it loaded the blazor.server.js file?

Answer (score 0):

As you've not provided a lot of code, I've built this code to try and reproduce your problem.

I can't: it works as I would expect it to.  So unless either answer above solves your problem, you'll need to provide more code.

Start point Blazor Server template.

New razor page - `_Test.cshtml`

```
@page "/Test"
@namespace BlazorApp8.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<h1>Counter in a Page</h1>
<div class="m-2 p-2">
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<Counter>(RenderMode.Server, new { Starter = 6}))
</div>
```

Update `Counter.razor` to take a parameter.

```
    [Parameter] public int Starter { get; set; } = 0;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        currentCount = this.Starter;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Run and navigate to `/Test`.

I get the Counter page, `OnInitialized` sets the initial count to 6 and clicking on the button increments the counter.

Comment: I can replicate the same thing starting with the Blazor Server Template, but I'm having troubles when I start with a ASP .NET Core Web App with razor pages template.  It goes back to the same problem of rendering, but not being 'connected'.

Comment: OK, so put your program,cs and razor file in your question.  It's hard trying to figure out your problem from one line of code :-)

Comment: After doing some digging, I think my problem is that my blazor component is being added by jquery in a partial view.  I don't think the ~/_framework/blazor.server.js "knows" about the component and can't interact with it.  Is there a way to restart the blazor connection after loading the partial view?

Comment: Where does JQuery suddenly come into this? [Polite] Apologies but we don't stand a hope of helping you without some code to work with.  I have no information if Blazor will run in a partial view, but I strongly suspect not.

Comment: Haha sorry for the confusion!  I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563910/how-to-add-blazor-component-loaded-to-page-from-jquery-and-ajax-call) with hopefully more clarity.

Comment: I can see it.  I'm walking away.  It looks like a dog's breakfast to me: a jumble of different technologies.  I'll be interested to see what comments you get.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the blazor section in your _Layout.cshtml with =>

```
<head>
...


<base href="~/"/>
</head>
...
   
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js" autostart="false" ></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        configureSignalR: function(builder) {
            builder.withUrl("_blazor");
        }
    });
</script>
...
```

Make sure to check your web console output. Blazor is likely throwing an error. This is pulled from every layout of every area in every app that I make. I've enjoyed a templated micro ui experience. Dotnet really makes it a breeze to proliferate your own designs via templates.