# How to add blazor component loaded to page from jquery and ajax call

Tags: razor, blazor

I have a new ASP .NET Razor pages app that I've configured for Blazor.

In the program.cs I've added

```
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();

...

app.MapBlazorHub();
```

In the Layout I've added:

```
<head>
    <base href="~/" />
    ...
</head>
...

<body>
    ...
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    ...
</body>
```

I added a Components folder with a Test.razor component:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Virtualization
@using Microsoft.JSInterop

@namespace RazorPagesApp.Components

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    [Parameter]
    public int InitialValue { get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        currentCount = InitialValue;
    }
}
```

In my Pages folder, I added a Test.cshtml page:

```
@page
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<button onclick="getComponentPartial();">Add Component Via Jquery</button>

<div id="componentPlaceholder"></div>
```

And a ComponentPartial.cshtml page:

```
@page
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<div id="PartialComponentDiv">
    <p>ServerPrerendered</p>
    <component type="typeof(Components.Test)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-InitialValue="20" />
</div>
```

Finally, in my site.js I added my ajax call:

```
function getComponentPartial() {
    try {
        $.get({
            url: 'ComponentPartial',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#componentPlaceholder').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

After running the project and navigating to https://localhost:7048/Test , I press the button to load the ComponentPartial page onto my test page.  The Test.razor component renders but is not interactive, I believe because the blazer.server.js does not have this listed as a component.  Is there a way to get this functional, i.e. have this component that was loaded via ajax and jquery be responsive via the blazor.server.js?